# Execute javascript without webview in Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to execute a JS fonction in my Android app.
The function is in a .js file on a website.

I'm not using webview, I want to execute the JS function because it sends the request i want.

In the Console in my browser i just have to do `question.vote(0);`, how can I do it in my app ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE 2018:** AndroidJSCore has been superseded by [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore), which is based on V8.  Not only does it include the V8 engine, but all of Node.js is available as well.

You can execute JavaScript without a WebView.  You can use [AndroidJSCore](https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore).  Here is a quick example how you might do it:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://your_website_here/file.js");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
String js = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

JSContext context = new JSContext();
context.evaluateScript(js);
context.evaluateScript("question.vote(0);");
```

However, this most likely won't work outside of a WebView, because I presume you are not only relying on JavaScript, but AJAX, which is not part of pure JavaScript.  It requires a browser implementation.

Is there a reason you don't use a hidden WebView and simply inject your code?

```
// Create a WebView and load a page that includes your JS file
webView.evaluateJavascript("question.vote(0);", null);
```

Comment: Excellent idea, Eric. An answer to your last question from 2023: one reason not to use a webview is that it only works for 5 minutes in the background in Android 13 (and a few lower also). So your answer is helpful for me.

Answer (score 6):

For the future reference, there is a library by square for this purpose.
https://github.com/square/duktape-android

This library is a wrapper for [Duktape](http://duktape.org), embeddable JavaScript engine.
You can run javascript without toying with WebView.

Duktape is Ecmascript E5/E5.1 compliant, so basic stuff can be done with this.

Comment: What are the benefits of duktape-android compaired to LiquidCore (previously known as AndroidJSCore)?