# Android Studio - JavaScript without WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, performance, webview

I have a very simple HTML which only contains a JavaScript. That's the body of the HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new fussballdeWidgetAPI().showWidget('widget1', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

Is there any alternative to show this website with a WebView, because it is very very slow? It takes about 10 seconds to load.

I already read something about making WebView faster like that

```
   WebSettings webSettings = webViewClubResult.getSettings();
   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
   webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
   webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
   webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

but it's still quite slow.

Is it possible to get rid of any kind of Browser but only display the JavaScript somehow?

Thank you very much

Comment: "I have a very simple HTML which only contains a JavaScript" -- what is this JavaScript doing? Is it generating a Web page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute javascript without webview in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089696/execute-javascript-without-webview-in-android)

Comment: I edited the post and added the body of the HTML