# Android Java access WebView in MainActivity from other class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have `public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService` to handle firebase notifications when the app is in the background.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        MainActivity.sendRegToken();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    public void sendRegToken() {
        String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:sendRegToken('"+recent_token+"');");
    }
}
```

I need access to `webView` so I can call `loadUrl`. `sendRegToken()` is a non-static method, and I'm trying to access it from a static context. I can't make `sendRegToken()` static because it contains the non-static `webView`. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Do you really need a `WebView` to send the token? A `WebView` is mainly a piece of UI, tied to an `Activity`. Even if there are ways to use it as a non-UI element, probably is not the best approach, and probably implementing the code to send the token as native would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use class [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)
Example can be found here : [LocalBroadcastManager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)
1.register broadcast on the MainActivity.
2.Send broadcast from `onTokenRefesh()` with parameters you need inside the Intent send.

Comment: Even if this solves the communication problem (`Service` -> `Activity`), as I said in my comment probably is not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not do that.

If you have an API for this communication, just use normal Http Requests, if you don't have an API see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34655101/4165135)

By the way, Greenrobot/EventBus way better and simpler than LocalBroadCastManager.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Haven't tried, but in theory it should work...

Use an Observer pattern.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    List<TokenRefreshListener> tokenListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTokenListener(TokenRefreshListener listener) {
       tokenListeners.add(listener);
   } 

  // Should also add a remove method

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = getToken();
        for (TokenRefreshListener l:tokenListeners) {
            l.onTokenRefresh(token);
        } 
    }
}
```

And define that interface

```
public interface TokenRefreshListener {
    void onTokenRefresh(String token);
}
```

And in the Activity, you need to implement that interface

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, 
    TokenRefreshListener {

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

     // need to call addTokenListener of the service 
     //... Probably do that in onStart method

     @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh(String token) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:sendRegToken('"+token+"');");
    }
}
```